# Split string in a loop

Tags: bash

I have an array in bash declared as follows:

```
declare -a StringArray=("A:100" "B:200" "C:300" "D:400 )
```

And I am trying to loop through and be able to print out the following format:

```
Letter - A
Value - 100
Letter - B
Value - 200
```

I tried the following code but it just prints out the whole string like this:

```
Letter - A:100
Value
Letter - B:200
```

```
export IFS=':'

for val in "${StringArray[@]}"; do
  echo "Letter - ${val[0]}"
  echo "Value - ${val[1]}"
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to populate an array in order to be able to use it with indices.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a StringArray=("A:100" "B:200" "C:300" "D:400" )

IFS=:
for tuple in "${StringArray[@]}"; do
    values=($tuple)
    echo "Letter - ${values[0]}"
    echo "Value - ${values[1]}"
done
```

Answer (score 5):

Demoing IFS string split and Associative array creation:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a StringArray=("A:100" "B:200" "C:300" "D:400" )

IFS=:
printf 'Letter - %s\nValue - %s\n' ${StringArray[@]}

declare -A StringAssoc="($(printf '[%q]=%q ' ${StringArray[@]}))"

typeset -p StringAssoc

for k in "${!StringAssoc[@]}"; do
  printf 'Letter - %s\nValue - %s\n' "$k" "${StringAssoc[$k]}"
done
```

Output:

```
Letter - A
Value - 100
Letter - B
Value - 200
Letter - C
Value - 300
Letter - D
Value - 400
declare -A StringAssoc=([D]="400" [C]="300" [B]="200" [A]="100" )
Letter - D
Value - 400
Letter - C
Value - 300
Letter - B
Value - 200
Letter - A
Value - 100
```

Note that iterating the associative array, the order of the entries is not preserved.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `read` after reading your elements:

```
for a in "${StringArray[@]}"; do
    IFS=: read v1 v2 _ <<< "$a" &&
    printf "Letter - %s\nValue - %s\n" "$v1" "$v2"
done
```

```
Letter - A
Value - 100
Letter - B
Value - 200
Letter - C
Value - 300
Letter - D
Value - 400
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner

```
printf "Letter - %s\nValue - %s\n" ${StringArray[*]//:/ }
```

will suffice if it is specified that array elements contain no space characters. No need to loop in this case.

Otherwise, a loop would be necessary:

```
StringArray=("A:100" "B:200" "C:300" "D:400" "E:a b")
for val in "${StringArray[@]}"; do
    IFS=: read -r name value <<< "$val"
    printf "Letter - %s\nValue - %s\n" "$name" "$value"
done
```

**Update**: After seeing Léa Gris' answer, it seems a loop isn't necessary for that case either. A simple

```
(IFS=:; printf 'Letter - %s\nValue - %s\n' ${StringArray[@]})
```

should work for all cases, provided that the `:` is always used as a separator. I'd prefer running it in a subshell in order not to mess up with the `IFS` of the current shell.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

next() {
[[ -s stack ]] && main
end
}

main() {
line=$(ed -s stack < edprint+.txt)
letter=$(echo "${line}" | cut -d':' -f1)
number=$(echo "${line}" | cut -d':' -f2)
echo "Letter = ${letter}.  Number = ${number}" >> report+.txt
ed -s stack < edpop+.txt
next
}

end() {
rm -v ./stack
rm -v ./edprint+.txt
rm -v ./edpop+.txt
exit 0
}

echo "A:100 B:200 C:300 D:400" | tr ' ' '\n' > stack

cat >> edprint+.txt << EOF
1
q
EOF

cat >> edpop+.txt << EOF
1d
wq
EOF

next
```

I also really don't like arrays, personally; but I try to refrain from telling other people not to use them, because it annoys me when others have told me not to use methods which I do like as well in the past, and I don't want to be a hypocrite.